# Pipewire Audio Stuttering and "spa.audioadapter"

Tags: audio, alsa, jack, pipewire

While using pipewire jack, I experience stuttering and other "artifacts" when playing complex projects in REAPER. My journal is being filled with messages of this kind:

> pipewire[1281]: spa.audioadapter: 0x5623327d2e28: scheduling stopped node

I looked online and couldn't find anything useful. Does anyone know what this might be referring too?